# How many combinations in a parliament?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Imagine a parliament with 4 parties that can form a government (this is a parliamentary democracy, not the US style democracy). The government does not need to have a majority behind it in the parliament (in the long run it does need it but not for this example).

How many possible combinations of parties are there?

I thought you calculated this using permutations but 4/4 returns 24 and when I do this manually I only come up with 15 combinations:

ABCD
ABC
ABD
ACD
BCD
AB
AC
AD
BC
BD
CD
A
B
C
D

https://www.calculatorsoup.com/calculators/discretemathematics/permutations.php?n=4&r=4&action=solve

In my case order does not matter (that is, ABC and CBA is the same) and items must not repeat. Does a regular permutation calculation take this into account? If not, how do I calculate this? Something like "combination (4 elements out of of 4 elements) + combination (3 of 4) + combination (2 of 4) + combination (1 of 4)"? What is this called?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can consider this as the power set of $\{A, B, C, D\}$ minus the empty set. This gives $2^4 - 1 = 15$ sets as required.

Comment: What is the relationship between "power sets" and permutations/combinations? I remember I had this function on my calculator (HP) during high school.